# How can I grab the time from the IE status bar?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, statusbar

I am using `IE` to run open a link and perform a calculation. These calculations take some time, and I'd like to generate an `excel` file that stores the calculation duration. Only time indication I'm currently aware of is the status bar on the bottom. How can I get that value and import it into an `Excel` worksheet?

Alternatively, if there's any other workaround to just getting the time required to run a page and storing the value, please let me know.

Best,
George

Comment: Difficult to make good suggestions without seeing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: CTRL-; gives the date. CTRL-: gives the time.

Comment: I just want to grab a handle of the value of the time as indicated by the Status bar in Internet Explorer and later store it in an Excel File. Will literally learn some html or javascript or whatever to learn how to do it.

I'd add an image.... but I dont have the reputation.